# Apply a predicate to the current node

Tags: xslt, xpath, xpath-1.0

*(I'm posting this self-answered question because the typically offered solution to this issue is needlessly verbose and I'd like to set the record straight. I couldn't find an existing SO question for this, but if there is one, please close this as a duplicate.)*

I am looking for a way to perform an XPath selection to select the current node only if it matches a certain condition. This would be useful, for example, when I want to conditionally apply an XSLT template to the current node:

```
<xsl:template match="Device">
  <div>
    <h2><xsl:value-of select="Name" /></h2>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="???[Featured = 'true']" mode="featured" />
    <p><xsl:value-of select="Description" /></p>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Book">
  <div>
    <h2><xsl:value-of select="Title" /></h2>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="???[FeaturedBook = 'true']" mode="featured" />
    <h3><xsl:value-of select="Author" /></h3>
    <p><xsl:value-of select="Summary" /></p>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()" mode="featured">
  <p class='featured-notice'>This is a featured item!
    <a href="/AddToCart?productId={Id}">Buy now</a> to get a 15% discount.
  </p>
</xsl:template>
```

I have tried using `.[Featured = 'true']`, but I get a syntax error. How can I do this?

*I'm not going to add an input and output here since they are tangential to the question and would make it exceedingly long, but if you want to see what I have in mind, I have placed them here: [input](http://pastebin.com/wLfr0RpP), [output](http://pastebin.com/iVx7qYaq).*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The syntax `.[predicate]` is not allowed in XPath 1.0 on account of the syntax rules (see the end of this post for the gritty details).

100% of the advice I have found says that the only option is to use `self::node()` for this:

```
self::node()[Featured = 'true']
```

[This XPath tester](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/7b5fd5355da73859eed1ca08cc20414d) is even specifically designed to tell users to use `self::node()[predicate]` if they try to use `.[predicate]`, but this is not the only option.

A valid and more concise option is to just wrap the abbreviated step in parentheses:

```
(.)[Featured = 'true']
```

This is perfectly valid by XPath 1.0 syntax rules (and in my opinion, a lot clearer).

You can also use this approach with the `..` abbreviated step, even going up multiple levels:

```
Select grandfather node if it is featured


../..[Featured = 'true']                - Not valid

../../../*[Featured = 'true']           - Valid, but not accurate

../../self::node()[Featured = 'true']   - Valid, but verbose

(../..)[Featured = 'true']              - Valid
```

---

**Addendum:** Why it's not possible to use `.[predicate]` in XPath 1.0

The following is the definition of a "step" in XPath 1.0 (basically, the pieces of an XPath node selection expression separated by slashes are called "steps"):

> [4]       Step       ::=      AxisSpecifier NodeTest Predicate* | AbbreviatedStep

This means that one step consists of one of two possible options:

- An axis specifier (which can be an empty string), followed by a node test, followed by 0 or more predicates
- An abbreviated step: `.` or `..`

There is no option to have an abbreviated step followed by predicates.

Comment: @IanRoberts It would for the example provided in the question because it's about XSLT, but `current()` is not part of the XPath standard and there _may_ be cases where `.` and `current()` refer to different things (such as inside a predicate) and you would want to use `.`.

Answer (score -1):

```
<xsl:template match="Device">
  <div>
    <h2><xsl:value-of select="Name" /></h2>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Featured[. = 'true']" />
    <p><xsl:value-of select="Description" /></p>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Book">
  <div>
    <h2><xsl:value-of select="Title" /></h2>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="FeaturedBook[. = 'true']" />
    <h3><xsl:value-of select="Author" /></h3>
    <p><xsl:value-of select="Summary" /></p>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FeaturedBook|Featured">
  <p class='featured-notice'>This is a featured item!
    <a href="/AddToCart?productId={Id}">Buy now</a> to get a 15% discount.
  </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The XSLT in the question was purely an illustrative example of the general question, and what you've posted there does not fulfill the intent of the example. I've edited the example to make that intent clearer.

Comment: You seem to have fixated on applying a predicate to the current node. What you are saying is - I'm here in the product template - now check to see if I should something. A better way is to externalize the check so you never go to the wrong template in the first place which you can do by placing the predicate in the template match statement. I've edited the code a little (not much)

Comment: I've fixated on applying a predicate to the current node because _that is what the question is about_. There are times when it's useful to be able to do so. As I already said, the XSLT example is purely an example. Nonetheless, if you think there is a more elegant way to do what the example is illustrating (and I apologize for changing it after the fact), then I welcome you to demonstrate it. Your current example doesn't tell me anything.

Comment: Your question is about how to go about doing something in an awkward way (the syntactical restriction you ran into is a hint) and what you have ended up with is over-complicated. If you want a better way post some sample input and sample output and I'll take another look.

Comment: I've edited the question to add links to an example input and output. And no, the fact that the syntactical grammar doesn't allow for it doesn't prove anything. If anything, the fact that `.[predicate]` is allowed in XQuery and XPath 2.0+ is an indication that it is worthwhile.

Comment: See edited code. Can Featured ever = false. If not you can remove the predicate against it.

Comment: Fair enough. There are always alternative ways to do things. You'd have to change `{Id}` to `{../Id}`, but your example works. I still stand by my assertion that this syntax is worth knowing and has practical applications, even if the example I provided isn't bulletproof.

Comment: Yes 1+2=3 and 1-1+1+2=3 are alternate ways of doing the same thing. I prefer the first.

Comment: I'm [not sure you always prefer the easy way of doing things](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25317785/1987598) to be honest.